# How to debugging C++ Code inside the C++/Cli wrapper

Tags: debugging, c++-cli, wrapper

Suppose this situation :

I have a dll which was written in standard c++, having a Class ,Native_Class, with function Native_F().

and I have a wrapper written in C++/CLI for Native_Class called Managed_Class with function Managed_F().

Then I use Manage_Class in C# and call its Managed_F().

When I add a breakpoint at the Managed_F() and press F11 in runtime it goes inside the function and if I press F11 again for going inside Native_F(), it does not work, indeed I can debug only to C++/CLI level and can not debug inside C++ implementations.

It is necessary for me to debug inside of c++ functions, please help me.

Maybe if I can introduce the pdb file of C++ project to C++/CLI project, I will solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the remote debugging. From visual studio with your c++ source code press Tools -> Attach To Process while running C# application.

Comment: Is your library is up-to-date? What exactly doesn't work? Are there any errors from vs, when you try to debug remotely?